# Changing background position and menu bar translucence

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I change the desktop background position (one of "Fill Screen", "Fit to Screen", "Stretch to Fill Screen", "Center" or "Tile") and the menu bar translucence (on or off) from code?

Basically I'd like to emulate the similar functionality form the "Desktop & Screen Saver" preference pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AppleScript, you can change the menu bar translucence:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set translucent menu bar of first desktop to false
end tell
```

There are various properties for the desktop picture – `change interval`, `picture`, `picture rotation`, `pictures folder`, and `random order` – but nothing about the background position. It may not be possible to configure that from code.

---

Update with Scripting Bridge technique:

In Terminal, do:

```
sdef /System/Library/CoreServices/System\ Events.app | sdp -fh --basename SystemEvents
```

Add the resulting SystemEvents.h into your project.  Import it into your code.  Add the ScriptingBridge framework to your target.

Then, in your code, you can do something like:

```
SystemEventsApplication* SystemEvents = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.systemevents"];
SystemEvents.currentDesktop.translucentMenuBar = FALSE;
```

You can read further about the Scripting Bridge [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Can I do the same using Objective-C?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the technique for using Scripting Bridge.

Comment: Is this specific to my system, or will it run everywhere, if I were to distribute the app via the Mac App Store?

Comment: After doing a clean build, I get the following error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Sorry. You have to add the ScriptingBridge framework to your project. And this will work anywhere. System Events is a standard part of Mac OS X. I'm not sure about the App Store, but I don't see why Apple would reject it. It's using only documented and supported techniques.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't seem right. Is the setting reflected in System Preferences? You could try toggling `+[NSMenu setMenuBarVisible:]` or maybe `-[NSApplication setPresentationOptions:]`.

Comment: It worked after all. I was running it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, but after moving it to a method executed on a button click, it worked fine.