# Setting the background picture position

Tags: objective-c, macos, app-store, applescript

Is there any Mac App Store compliant way of setting the desktop wallpaper position to "Stretch to Fill Screen"?

Comment: I see you've already discussed the issue on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120313/changing-background-position-and-menu-bar-translucence), so I'm going to assume this didn't solve your problem. For the benefit of the rest of us, would you mind extrapolating a bit on what you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This code sample from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DesktopImage/Introduction/Intro.html) provides a  good overview of the problem and how to properly code for it in Cocoa. The salient code snippet appears to be the following:

```
- (void)updateScreenOptions:(NSScreen*)screen
{
    if (screen)
    {
        NSDictionary *screenOptions = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] desktopImageOptionsForScreen:curScreen];

        // the value is an NSNumber containing an NSImageScaling (scaling factor)
        NSNumber *scalingFactor = [screenOptions objectForKey:NSWorkspaceDesktopImageScalingKey];
        [scalingPopup selectItemAtIndex:[scalingFactor integerValue]];

        // the value is an NSNumber containing a BOOL (allow clipping)
        NSNumber *allowClipping = [screenOptions objectForKey:NSWorkspaceDesktopImageAllowClippingKey];
        [[clippingCheckbox cell] setState:[allowClipping boolValue]];

        // the value is an NSColor (fill color)
        NSColor *fillColorValue = [screenOptions objectForKey:NSWorkspaceDesktopImageFillColorKey];
        if (fillColorValue)
            [fillColor setColor:fillColorValue];
    }
}
```

As mentioned in [some of the answer errata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10180262/517815), the correct method calls here to resolve your question appear to be `[screenOptions setObject:scalingFactor forKey:NSWorkspaceDesktopImageScalingKey]` and `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setDesktopImageURL:imageURL forScreen:curScreen options:screenOptions error:&error]`, which should provide the desired functionality.

I freely admit [this was a collaborative effort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10180262/517815), but it seems we've blundered through to a correct solution.

(Additional information on the [`NSImageScaling`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSImageScaling) enumeration and [`NSWorkspace`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which contains the correct scaling keys.)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no Mac App Store compliant way of setting the desktop image options. They only methods available with regards to desktop images are:

```
– desktopImageURLForScreen:
– setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:
– desktopImageOptionsForScreen:
```

You may be able to do it by executing an AppleScript, though I do not think Apple will like that.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

```
[screenOptions setObject:scalingFactor forKey:NSWorkspaceDesktopImageScalingKey];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setDesktopImageURL:imageURL forScreen:curScreen options:screenOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: `desktopImageOptionsForScreen` you say... Wouldn't setting `NSWorkspaceDesktopImageScalingKey` to `NSImageScaleAxesIndependently` accomplish this?

Comment: i'm pretty sure it can be done with Applescript, I've seen an example of someone changing system preferences, which is basically the same.

Comment: `- desktopImageOptionsForScreen:` does not allow you to set the options, you pass in the NSScreen and get back a dictionary with the data. Try to contact dev support, they will know if you are allowed to use Applescript to change system prefs.

Comment: @sgonzalez, oh, I see now that you can't set it... Even if I could use AppleScript, the System Preferences app is not scriptable, so I think the only option I'd have there is to actually start the app and instruct it what buttons to press using AppleScript...

Comment: I think the salient takeaway here is this is a case where Apple has restricted the ability for developers to programmatically update System Preferences, precisely because it would break their unified design paradigm. You can, however, create a function that opens the System Preferences app and guides the user, but you cannot update its settings programmatically and expect it to get through Apple's review process. I'm going to do a little digging and see if I can find a primary source on that decision, just to tie this up with a nice little bow for anyone else running into this exact issue.

Comment: An alternative may be to instruct the user how to change the preference. Why do you need to change the content mode? If you are wanting to change the background picture with one of your own, you can scale the image programmatically to be the same size as the current screen.

Comment: @MrGomez, well, apparently you can set *everything else* about the desktop background (what the desktop picture is, or a series of them, when to change them, etc), just not this (or at least I didn't find any way to set this), so I'm not sure if it's anything related to the unified design paradigm. If this specific functionality is indeed missing for some reason, then that's that, but I want to make sure.

Comment: @sgonzalez, that's what I was thinking, if there's absolutely no way of doing this particular thing, then I'll just scale it myself... I was hoping I didn't have to though...

Comment: @Radu Agreed. I'm going to have a look. No promises, but it's the best I can do here. :)

Comment: And as long as I'm digging around: I found [some sample code from Apple that might be useful here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DesktopImage/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: @MrGomez, I see they use `[screenOptions setObject:scalingFactor forKey:NSWorkspaceDesktopImageScalingKey];` then `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setDesktopImageURL:imageURL forScreen:curScreen options:screenOptions error:&error]`! This looks like it should work!

Comment: @Radu Yep! I'm in the process of throwing it into an answer. It's pretty amazing what the right Google queries can do. :)

Comment: @MrGomez, you're obviously a much better Googler than me.

Comment: @Radu Actually, I was lucky. [`NSWorkspace`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) contained a link under _Related sample code_, which led me to the correct solution. I'm honestly not sure how I overlooked it before.